# Can I use PS3 controllers on a PS2

Tags: ps3, controllers, ps2

Is there a way to use a Playstation 3 controller with a Playstation 2?  (Perhaps with a wireless dongle plugged into the front of the PS2..)

Our PS2 controllers are getting knackered, and I'm loathed to replace them if there is a way to use our PS3 controllers instead.

Comment: Go back in time and buy a 60Gb PS3 with PS2 backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 6):

Unless Sony made the controllers send the same signals and have the same connectors there's no way that a PS2 can talk to a device created *in the future* without some intermediate hardware (as you suggest). However, it's not really in Sony's interest to do this themselves.

[Wiki Answers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_you_use_a_PS3_controller_on_a_PS2) and [Answer Bag](http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/719766) would appear to agree with me.

Though you're [not the only one](http://share.blog.us.playstation.com/ideas/2010/04/06/ps3-controllers-on-ps2/) suggesting this. Though I don't see any answers that suggest how it might be done. Some sort of device like the USB to PS/2 converter you can get for PC mice and keyboards is what you need.

Comment: I'd imagine purchasing an adaptor that plugs into the controller ports of the PS2.  This adaptor would wirelessly connect to the PS3 controllers, and output the right PS2 signals to the PS2.

Comment: @pauldoo - perhaps, but a manufacturer would have to see a market.

Comment: Regarding making something from the past compatible with something from the future, I would flip that around.  Many USB mice, for example, are PS/2 compatible with just some rewiring.

Comment: @Nick - that's a good point I hadn't thought of.